# What should I do with my outdated comment on a locked question?

Tags: support, comments, locked-posts

I wanted to delete an outdated comment of mine on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483398/python-routes-issues-using-flask) which has been merged with a duplicate post and is now locked.

When clicking on `Delete`, there was a red error popup saying

> Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting

Since this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330667/289905), what should I do in such cases?

- Should I just leave the comment for future readers? But it was really not needed anymore.
- Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: This obviously isn’t exclusive to Stack Overflow; the feature request to allow this lives on Meta Stack Exchange: [Let us delete our own comments even if the post is locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330667/289905). _“But I don't want to vote on it, I want to delete it.”_ — Clicking “Delete” is a special type of vote.

Comment: This behaviour is currently as per design... I've deleted the comment anyway but the link @user4642212 points out has the background info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment wasn't causing any harm by being there but I agree it was redundant with the question banner and you should really be able to remove it yourself.

If you do choose to flag your comment to ask for removal then make sure you make it very clear in the reason that the post is currently locked and you're not able to remove the comment because of that or you'd have done it yourself.